# Wrapper around a Python API for creating user interfaces

Tags: python, user-interface

I am writing a wrapper around the `GeUserArea` class of [Cinema 4D](http://maxon.de)'s Python API to enable creating user interfaces using an object orientated interface.

I've already written 2 prototypes, but I am **not** satisfied with my class-design.
They *do* work very well, but I decided to start over to make it even more efficient, more clean and better commented, etc.

The `GeUserArea` class provides drawing on it as it was a field of pixels, so it's a highly dynamic class to enable almost any type of interface you want, when you have the skills.

The baseclass for all objects being rendered is the `Renderable` class.
Two of the subclasses are `View` and `Lable`. The difference between these is, that `View` does hold a `frame` attribute that defines a rectangular area while `Lable` does only hold a *position* attribute that defines the position of the text being rendered.

The `Renderable` class implements a tree-like design, so you can add a `Renderable` instance below another, etc. When an input event (mouse/keyboard) appears, a chain starts that tells the full tree that this event occured. Any `Renderable` instance should be able to react on an input event. But the view-subclass should also call a method when the mouse clicked into it's area.

(Theese methods are to let the user override them while subclassing, enabling to react on those input events.)

The event itself comes from `GeUserArea.InputEvent(self, msg)`.
From the `msg` parameter, I can read out if and where a mouse event took place.
After doing so, the event chain starts.

```
class Renderable:
    def InputEvent(self, msg):
        pass

class View(Renderable):
    def MouseEvent(self, msg, mouse):
        pass
```

Using the above layout, I'd need to implement a method that manages calling of theese methods, like this:

```
class Renderable:
    # ..
    def _private_ManageInput(self, msg):
        self.InputEvent(msg)
        for sub in self.subs:
            sub._private_ManageInput(msg)

class View(Renderable):
    # ..
    def _private_ManageInput(self, msg):
        if IsMouseEvent(msg):
            mouse = GetMouse(msg)
            if mouse in self.frame:
                self.MouseEvent(self, msg, mouse)
        Renderable._private_ManageInput(self, msg)
```

This does already seem a bit dirty to me.

As the mouse position doesn't change within the recursive chain, it makes more sense to give the mouse position as an argument to the `Renderable._private_ManageInput()` method, which gives a speedup of about 30%.

```
class Renderable:
    # ..
    def _private_ManageInput(self, msg, mouse):
        self.InputEvent(msg)
        for sub in self.subs:
            sub._private_ManageInput(msg)

class View(Renderable):
    # ..
    def _private_ManageInput(self, msg, mouse):
        if mouse is not None:
            if mouse in self.frame:
                self.MouseEvent(msg, mouse)
        Renderable._private_ManageInput(self, msg, mouse)
```

The `Renderable` class does not implement reacting on `MouseEvents` (as it does not define any area where the mouse could "hit" it), but a method does need arguments for this purpose?  It seems quite dirty to me.

Can you tell me how I can improve this design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is ensure that events only reach those who are interested in that particular type of event. Right now you seem to be sending out a generic events that you then check to see what type they are.

I wrote a similar answer some time ago to another question on Stack Overflow. You can read it here:
► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249388/7294148#7294148

Comment: The idea with the EventManager is a pretty good one and I think is easy to implement in this case. I will try it out, thank you so far !